# sql select max for each grouped column and rest of row

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql

```
name    year    data
a       1        1
b       1        2 
c       2        3
a       2        4
c       3        5
```

For each year I need the max(data), year, and name associated with that max.

ive tried

`select max(data), name , year from table group by year;` however I do not have access to name.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are grouping by year, you will have a row per year. If so which name do you want to display? e.g  for the year 2, it could be a or c? (maybe assume they have the same `max(data)`.

Comment: @danblack for year 2 i should get a, 2, 4

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 15.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try something like below

```
select name, data, year from table A
join (select max(data) data, year from table a
group by year) B on A.data = B.data and A.year = B.year
```